# How to write Active Record with "and" and "or" conditions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to write Active Record with three `and` condition(must) and two `or` conditions.

I wrote this:

```
@properties = Property.where(category_id: 2).
                       where(status: 3).
                       where(p_type: 'sell')`
```

This lists the query with `and` conditions.

I need to include two `or` conditions at the end.

It tried this but got an error:

```
@properties = Property.where(category_id: 2).
                       where(status: 3).
                       where(p_type: 'sell').
                       or(location: @location).
                       or(featured: '1)`
```

How do I do it?

Comment: you can try this `@properties = Property.where(category_id: 2, status: 3).where("(p_type = ? OR location = ? OR featured = ?)", 'sell', @location, '1')`

Comment: Thanks amit. this code is working :)

Comment: The `where().or()` method chain will be available in Rails 5. It was added [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including all of the final link on that page. Grammar and capitalization is important on Stack Overflow because it's a reference book of programming questions and solutions in the making. Not taking time to do it sends a message that it wasn't important enough to you, which actually affects people's willingness to help you. We understand English might not be your primary language, so sometimes it helps having a peer review the question. So, help yourself get answers by taking the time. Mkay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
@properties = Property.where(category_id: 2, status: 3).where("(p_type = ? OR location = ? OR featured = ?)", 'sell', @location, '1')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@properties=Property.where("(category_id = ? AND status = ? ) OR (location = ? OR featured = ?)", "2", "3", @location, "1")
```